Why are rotated parallel axes still parallel?
Suppose the axes in two coordinate systems S, S' are parallel. Now, suppose I rotate S through some angle $\theta$, and also rotate S' through the same angle $\theta$. It's not clear to me that the rotated axes will remain parallel. In relativity, angles are coordinate dependent. For example, if S and S' are parallel and S' moves at velocity |v|$\hat x$ relative to S, and someone in S' places a bar at an angle of $\theta$ with respect to the axis x', then this angle will not be the same as the angle relative to the x axis. If someone in S then places a bar at an angle $\theta$ with respect to x, then am I correct that this bar won't be parallel to the bar in S' since an observer in S measures the bars at different angles relative to the x axis?  However, these bars are just rotated axes, both rotated at the same angle $\theta$, but they're not parallel.

Why do you think they are not parallel? Or you think they are, and would like to see a proof.

@ClaudioSaspinski I think they are parallel. For example, this is used in deriving the formula for a generalized Lorentz transformation. In my original post, I argued that they are not parallel, and I don't see what's wrong with the argument.

Related : Parallel axes between inertial frames in Special Relativity.

Related : How to represent a pair of inertial frames in relativity?.

The Lorentz group contains both ordinary rotations and boosts. Any Lorentz transformation may be written generally in terms of an ordinary rotation and a pure boost: $\Lambda=RL=\tilde{R}\tilde{L}$ So that a Lorentz transformation From some third frame $K$, also parallel to $S$ and $S^\prime$, will be given as:
$$\Lambda=RL=\tilde{L}\tilde{R};\;\;\text{For K to S}$$
and:
$$\Lambda=R L^\prime=\tilde{R}\tilde{L^\prime};\;\; \text{For K to S}^\prime.$$
Because the $S$ and $S^\prime$ are rotated by the same amount, the same rotation $R$ is used in either case, thus it is obvious that if $S$ and $S^\prime$ were parallel in $K$ then the transformed frames are also parallel.

Did you mean Lambda = RL = R tilda L tilda; For K to S?

@user7348 No, I am simply saying that the order you choose doesn't matter, i.e. you may boost then rotate, or rotate then boost, however, the transformations used in each specific ordering change accordingly. This is because in general rotations and boosts do not commute, e.g. $RL\neq LR$

@user7348 Basically, rotations and boosts are independent of each other.

Where does my argument that the axes aren't parallel go wrong?

@user7348 Because your argument does not assume the independence of rotations and boosts. The rotated axis will be related to the unrelated axis by a boost and a rotation, if you a priori assume that the rotation is through an angle $\theta$ then that will not change when you perform the boost.  Perhaps this might be a better way to think about it: contraction is occurring in both the $x^\prime$ and $y^\prime$ axis, because the $y^\prime$ axis is no longer perpendicular to the $x$ axis.

@user7348 The above should show how thinking about rotated coordinates axis is a little bit different from thinking about a vector in $S^\prime$, where $S^\prime$ and $S$ are parallel.

I'm not really understanding what's going on. I think I'm going to delete the question and post it on the physicsforums which is better fitted for an ongoing discussion. Thanks.

Well, I guess I'm not supposed to delete the question, but I'm still going to discuss this further on the physicsforums.
